# How to understand iOS plist.info BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers property?

Tags: ios, swift, info.plist

I found a lot of questions regarding the error from XCode when submitting a new app and this property is not set in the info.plist file. I'm still not sure why this property is needed at all but ok...

I tried to figure out what entries are required here for an app, but I'm not sure after reading a lot of questions and solutions.

I added now:

```
<array>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
</array>
```

So this means my defined product identifier's app can start background tasks and they can run in the background.

Question 1:
What is, when I have another target for Push Notifications and a Widget?
Do I have to add every target in my project? Because Push notifications are usually received when the app is in the background. So is this necessary or only when the there are background tasks started in this target?

Question 2:
What is with external Frameworks? Do they have to define that on their own or do I have to add every bundle identifier for a Framework which may do some stuff in the background?

Question 3:
Can i add Wildcards? so if my app has multiple targets which have the same beginning (com.companyname.productname_x1,com.companyname.productname_x2) and i need to specify all of them as a result of Question 1 can i just add com.companyname.*

Than you for your help!